# Triggers between different databases on different hosts

Tags: mysql, triggers, synchronization

I need to keep two different databases in sync. Triggers seem to be the best thing to do, but the two databases are on different hosts. Most of the triggers tutorials I've seen seem to assume the triggers update different tables on the same database, or at least on the same host.

Is there any way to configure a database to update another database on a completely different server with triggers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. That can't be done with regular triggers.

MySQL does allow for User Defined Functions to be written in other languages; that gives the advantage of accessing resources not available from within MySQL. The User Defined Function could be invoked from a trigger, but there are some significant disadvantages to this approach; I don't think you (or anyone else) really wants to go that route. I just mention it, because it is available.

As an alternative, you could have a separate process, running externally from MySQL doing the synchronization.

From a trigger, you could insert rows into a "transaction" table. An external process could poll the "transaction" table for new rows, and connect to other databases (even non-MySQL databases) and issue DML, or do whatever, and mark the rows in the "transaction" table as completed, failed, or whatever.  But this would be an asynchronous approach, rather than synchronous, and the trigger wouldn't have any way of "knowing" if the transaction was successfully completed on the remote system.

As another alternative, MySQL provides replication features, the binary logs can be shipped to remote databases, to keep "slave" databases replicated from the "master".

But, if you were asking if you could get that to happen using the native syntax available in a DML trigger, the answer is no, that's not going to happen.

---

There are other databases (such as Oracle and SQL Server) which DO support connections to remote databases from within the database (Oracle "database links" and SQL Server "linked servers". Those also support two-phase commit, so you can have do real "multi-database" transactions.

Comment: Not entirely true - you can use the FEDERATED storage engine to connect to a table in a remote database. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/create-a-trigger-to-update-table-data-on-another-servers-database for more.